# Security for file uploads in Java

Tags: java, security, file-upload

I have a web application using Java Servlets in which the user can upload files.  What can I do to prevent malicious files and viruses from being uploaded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [ClamAV antivirus](http://www.clamav.net/lang/en/) team provide a [very easy interface for integrating the `clamd` daemon](http://www.clamav.net/doc/latest/html/node28.html) into your own programs. It is sockets-based instead of API based, so you might need to write some convenience wrappers to make it look "natural" in your code, but the end result is they do not need to maintain a dozen or more language bindings.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, if you have enough access to the machine in question, you could simply call a command line application to do the scanning. There is enough info on starting command line applications and most if not all locally installed virusscanners have a command line option. This has the advantage that not every IP packet has to pass through the scanner (but you will have to read and parse the output of the virusscanner). It also makes sure you got the info available in your Java application so you can warn the user.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to protect from Path Traversal (making sure users cannot upload files to a place they do not belong, such as overwriting a JAR file in the classpath or a DLL in the path)

Comment: against Path Traversal attack you need to normalize the path http://stackoverflow.com/a/28053872/1582089