# Java: how to normalize paths with nio Path?

Tags: java, nio

One of the really nice things about `java.io.File` is that it can **normalize paths** to a **predictable format**.

`new File("/", inputPath).getPath()` always returns a string with relative paths normalized out, and always starting and ending with predictable path separators.

Is there a way to do this with the new nio `Path` or `Paths` classes?

(Note also that I am dealing with abstract paths for other systems, this has nothing to do with any local filesystem)

Further examples of behavior I want:

```
 - "/foo" -> "/foo"
 - "//foo/" -> "/foo"
 - "foo/" -> "/foo"
 - "foo/bar" -> "/foo/bar"
 - "foo/bar/../baz" -> "/foo/baz"
 - "foo//bar" -> "/foo/bar"
```

Comment: The reasons I want to use the nio API are nice additions like Paths.get() (which feels cleaner than new File()) and Path.subpath(). I'm just trying to mix those in with the existing simplicity of the normalization we get with new File("/", input).

Comment: And may I also add, as a comment to the universe, that it is extremely confusing that java.io.FileSystem and java.nio.file.FileSystem both exist.

Comment: See edit to my answer (and I don't know where you saw `java.io.FileSystem` at all)

Comment: java.io.File uses java.io.Filesystem.  It has a native concept of a default FileSystem.

Comment: A related question which is part of why I want to use java.nio: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28058287/concise-ways-to-split-paths-using-java-nio

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This code works:

```
public final class Foo
{
    private static final List<String> INPUTS = Arrays.asList(
        "/foo", "//foo", "foo/", "foo/bar", "foo/bar/../baz", "foo//bar"
    );

    public static void main(final String... args)
    {
        Path path;

        for (final String input: INPUTS) {
            path = Paths.get("/", input).normalize();
            System.out.printf("%s -> %s\n", input, path);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
/foo -> /foo
//foo -> /foo
foo/ -> /foo
foo/bar -> /foo/bar
foo/bar/../baz -> /foo/baz
foo//bar -> /foo/bar
```

NOTE however that this is NOT portable. It won't work on Windows machines...

If you want a portable solution you can use [memoryfilesystem](https://github.com/marschall/memoryfilesystem), open a Unix filesystem and use that:

```
try (
    final FileSystem fs = MemoryFileSystem.newLinux().build();
) {
    // path operations here
}
```

Comment: toAbsolutePath() appears to prepend the working directory of the java process for anything that doesn't start with a path separator (which is not what I'm looking for... I'm not dealing with the local filesystem at all). toRealPath() tries to actually go find the path on the local filesystem.

Comment: If you are not dealing with the local filesystem, this means you don't use `Paths.get()` to retrieve your paths, right?

Comment: OK, I'm not really sure what you want to do, but just try and normalize the result of `Paths.get("/", "yourpathhere")`. That should do it.

Comment: Ah, good point. I have actually had success so far using Paths.get(), but reading more closely, the underlying Filesystem might indeed have incompatibilities with what I'm trying to do. I guess that means that the answer is "no, you can only use nio Paths to deal with real, local filesystems. Abstract file path concepts must be dealt with using java.io.File or with custom code".

Comment: @TREE: what? Path is supposed to abstract filesystems away in a way File can't.  Did you mean it the other way around?

Comment: `Paths.get` should _only_ be used for the real local file system, but `FileSystem.getPath` is how you get a `Path` into another filesystem.

Comment: Actually *both* are, in fact, using a FileSystem object to perform certain operations (but not the same one, for strange reasons). By definition, both APIs are dependent on the local filesystem. The API for Path does more things with the local filesystem than the API for File, though, making it less useful for the abstract operations I want to perform. I *really* don't want to re-implement subpath, though. :(

Comment: The way their design was built was intended to be the other way around; `Path` was specifically intended to abstract away the local filesystem.  I'm not sure I understand what you're referring to with regards to "things with the local filesystem that Path does," but I suspect that that's a side effect of you misusing Path, not a failing in the Path API.

Comment: @LouisWasserman I'm looking for a way to do the operations as described in the question, using the nio.file APIs. They're trivial with a File, but no one has proposed a concise equivalent for Path.

Comment: `normalize()` appears to be fine, but `toAbsolutePath()`'s doc mentions its dependence on the local filesystem.  I think `toString` might actually be what you want instead?

Comment: @LouisWasserman toString() does not always start with a leading path separator.

Comment: @Tree: I think the leading path separator should be part of how you build the `Path`, not how you're formatting it in output, as per @fge's suggestion earlier?

Comment: @LouisWasserman The goal is to normalize input to a consistent form. It doesn't actually matter whether the leading path separator is present as long as it is *consistently* either present or absent.

Comment: The path `/foo` is strictly different from the path `foo`, because paths can be combined relative to the other: evaluating `foo/bar` relative to `baz` gets you `baz/foo/bar`, whereas evaluating `/foo/bar` gets you `/foo/bar` wherever you are.  If all the paths you're operating on are intended to be evaluated relative to root, then you should add a leading `/` when building the `Path`.

Comment: @TREE `Path` is more "abstract" than `File`; no operation on `Path` itself, apart from `.to{Absolute,Real}Path()` will need the filesystem for anything. As I said, prefix all your paths you get with a leading slash. Since this is the root of a Unix filesystem, `.toAbsolutePath()` will just use the name elements starting from the root. Note that if you want an "abstract" filesystem you may try and use [memoryfilesystem](https://github.com/marschall/memoryfilesystem) for these operations.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Yes, they are different, which is why it is important for me to get them in the right format for my use case. It would be an error to have them in the wrong format, which is why I'm not accepting answers that don't put them in the right format, for my use case. This is explained in detail, with examples, in the question.

Comment: @fge Please update your answer (or perhaps, since there is so much discussion on this one, write a new one) to include your recommendation that addresses the question.

Comment: @TREE: I meant that if they're not coming out in a consistent format, I think it's because you're not putting them in in a  consistent format.  If you normalize `foo/bar/..` and `/foo/bar/..`, then you should get different results.  If you post in your question the exact code you're using, the inputs you're providing, and the outputs you're getting, then we can advise you on how to fix them.