# Concise ways to split paths using java.nio?

Tags: java, nio

I'm trying to split a path using Path.subpath, but the resulting code seems ridiculously verbose. **Is there a more concise/idiomatic way to accomplish this?**

```
//input from elsewhere
String userInput = "foo/bar//baz/";
int splitPoint = 1; 

Path startPath = Paths.get(userInput).normalize();
int nameCount = startPath.getNameCount();
String leftSide = splitPoint > 0 
    ? Paths.get("/", startPath.subpath(0, splitPoint).toString()).toString()
    : "/";
String rightSide = splitPoint < nameCount 
    ? Paths.get("/", startPath.subpath(splitPoint, nameCount).toString()).toString()
    : "/";
```

Note that I need both resulting String paths to start with "/". And I'm aware of the platform-specific issues around path separator and other filesystem specifics.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:

```
final int nameCount = startPath.getNameCount();

final List<Path> elements = new ArrayList<>(nameCount);

for (int i = 0; i < nameCount; i++)
    list.add(startPath.getName(i));

final Path head = Paths.get("/");
final Path tail = Paths.get("/");

for (final Path entry: elements.sublist(0, splitPoint))
    head = head.resolve(entry);

for (final Path entry: elements.sublist(splitPoint, nameCount))
    tail = tail.resolve(entry);
```

Comment: I need both halves. This is also just a partial reimplementation of subpath, and doesn't actually address the question.